# Setting up auditd on FreeBSD 13 to log user commands

Tags: freebsd, audit

I modified `/etc/security/audit_control` by adding the `ex` ("exec") and `ad` ("administrative") audit classes to the `flags`:

```
flags:lo,aa,ex,ad
```

I enabled and started the service

```
service auditd enable
service auditd start
```

Now, I run `praudit /dev/auditpipe`, but it prints nothing when I execute commands in another terminal. I can see user login events but not commands:

```
header,97,11,su(1),0,Sun Nov  6 18:48:54 2022, + 32 msec
subject,-1,root,wheel,root,wheel,77911,77911,0,0.0.0.0
text,successful authentication
return,success,0
trailer,97
```

What am I missing?

```
# cat /etc/security/audit_control
#
# $FreeBSD$
#
dir:/var/audit
dist:off
flags:lo,aa,ex,ad
minfree:5
naflags:lo,aa
policy:cnt,argv
filesz:2M
expire-after:10M
```

Answer (score 3):

After changing `/etc/security/audit_control` and starting the auditing service (or running `audit -s` as root if the service is already running), the new settings take effect when a user logs in.
Users already logged in will not be audited with the changed configuration.  This is hinted at in [the `audit_user(5)` manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=audit_user):

> The `audit_user` file specifies which audit event classes are to be audited
> for the given users.  If specified, these flags are combined with the
> system-wide audit flags in the `audit_control(5)` file to determine which
> classes of events to audit for that user.  **These settings take effect
> when the user logs in.**

("These settings" refer to the settings in the two files, not just the `audit_user` file.)

Adding the `ex` and `ad` flags to the `audit_control` configuration, as you've done,  running `audit -s` as root (as I already have auditing enabled), logging in on another line, and typing `ls`, I see the following in the audit log generated by the `ls` command:

```
header,119,11,execve(2),0,Tue Nov  8 07:00:53 2022, + 503 msec
exec arg,ls,-F
path,/bin/ls
attribute,555,root,wheel,1425188585,14654,629136184
subject,myself,myself,myself,myself,myself,21223,21212,57410,192.168.1.107
return,success,0
trailer,119
header,148,11,execve(2),0,Tue Nov  8 07:00:53 2022, + 510 msec
exec arg,git,rev-parse,--git-dir
path,/usr/local/bin/git
attribute,755,root,wheel,1425188585,279022,407440184
subject,myself,myself,myself,myself,myself,21224,21212,57410,192.168.1.107
return,success,0
trailer,148
```

You can see that I have `ls` aliased to `ls -F`. The second entry showing a `git` command is due to my interactive shell's prompt.